# Razor validation firing without [required] attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

Here is my model

```
public class SchoolUser
{
    public int schoolId { get; set; }

    public int contact1UserId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DataLayer.salutations> Salutations { get; set; }

    public int departmentId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DataLayer.departments> Departments { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int roleId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DataLayer.rolesView> roles { get; set; }
```

Here is my razor code for creating dropdown for deptartmentid view

```
                <div style="width:75%; display:inline-block; margin-left:5px;">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.departmentId, new SelectList(Model.Departments, "deptId", "description"), "")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.departmentId)
                </div>
```

What confuses us to no end, razor validation complains when no dept is chosen. But the school model had no [required] attribute.

**"The departmentId field is required."**

Looking at page source I see

```
 <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field departmentId must be a number." data-val-required="The departmentId field is required." id="departmentId" name="departmentId"><option value=""></option>
<option value="30">English</option>
</select>
```

For some reason, the razor view engine has 'decided' to require this field to be populated even though the model has no [required] or other constraining attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.net MVC3 DropDownListFor int Required DataAnnotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550372/asp-net-mvc3-dropdownlistfor-int-required-dataannotation)

Comment: @TimBJames, the issue in your link has nothing to do with the issue I ran into.

Comment: 3 months later, some winner comes along and anonymously snipes me. must be some anonymous genius who knows everything! :)

Comment: +1 to top you back up :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not nullable.
You should change it to int? .

Comment: Of course, now that I think about it, if the ints not nullable, it cant get a null!!!! @Zote, you ROCK!

Comment: +1 simple but true -remeber having the same head scratching a few yrs back.